# What free Windows browsers have VPNs built in, other than Epic, Opera, Tor?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Software Recommendations Stack Exchange post: [What free Windows browsers have VPNs built in, other than Epic, Opera, Tor?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83177/what-free-windows-browsers-have-vpns-built-in-other-than-epic-opera-tor)

Why was this deleted by a sole moderator — when [What Android browsers have VPNs built in?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/77165) remains openm and explained what's wrong with Opera and Tor?

[Yisroel Tech](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/29181/yisroel-tech) alleged

> [This is a spam post, and seems to be meant as to backlink this unknown Epic browser (listed first since it's more known than the other two mentioned...)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83177/what-free-windows-browsers-have-vpns-built-in-other-than-epic-opera-tor?noredirect=1#comment102643_83177)

Yisroel Tech is wholly wrong, and this allegation is groundless. I linked to Epic merely to identify what browser I was referring. You can remove the link, if you disbelieve me.

#### Notice of Non-Affiliation and Disclaimer

I am not at all affiliated, associated, or backed by, any browser or its subsidiaries or affiliates.

Answer (score 1):

[What Android browsers have VPNs built in?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77165) is also not a great question in my opinion, because a big part of the question is about a service, rather than about software. I would not be surprised if it gets closed by the community.